# Why does Amazon Glacier WJPSGlacier vault Size show '--'?

Tags: nas, amazon-web-services, qnap, amazon-glacier

I have set up my QNAP NAS to backup to Amazon Glacier which seems to work well. However when I login to AWS the vault I am backing up to it shows the vault is empty, size 0, inventory last updated not available, etc. See the image below.

[image]

Any idea what's going on? QNAP isn't showing any issues, and I am being billed by AWS for the usage I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The vault inventory is updated approximately once a day.
You will see correct size and number of archives in 1-2 days.

Andrey, work for CloudBerry